# Update de Array de Telefone no banco de dados

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, .net-core

Estou tentando realizar o Update de informações em meu banco de dados aonde que tenho `1:N` entre `Clientes` e `Telefones`, mas não estou conseguindo realizar tal update, porque as vezes será necessário retirar um telefone que esta no banco, as vezes adicionar um novo telefone e manter os que já estão inseridos, e as vezes será necessário realizar as duas operações conjunta, poderiam me ajudar ?

Meu Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(EditClientViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var client = await _clientManager.GetClientIdAsync(model.Id);

            if (client == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException($"Não é possível carregar o cliente com o ID '{client.Id}'.");
            }

            client.Nome = model.Name;
            client.RazaoSocial = model.CompanyName;
            client.NomeFantasia = model.FantasyName;
            client.Cpfj = model.Cpfj;
            client.CEP = model.CEP;
            client.UF = model.UF;
            client.Bairro = model.Neighborhood;
            client.Cidade = model.City;
            client.Endereco = model.Address;
            client.Numero = model.Number;
            client.Complemento = model.Complement;
            client.DataNascimento = model.BirthDate;
            client.TipoPessoa = model.TypePerson;

            var result = await _clientManager.UpdateClientAsync(client);

            foreach (var ClientTelephone in client.ClientesTelefone)
            {
                foreach (var NewClientTelephone in model.Telephone)
                {
                    if(ClientTelephone.ToString() != NewClientTelephone && NewClientTelephone != null)
                    {
                        var clientTelephone = new ApplicationClientTelephone
                        {
                            Telefone = NewClientTelephone,
                            Cliente = client
                        };

                        await _clientManager.UpdateClientTelephoneAsync(clientTelephone);
                    }
                }
            }

            TempData["MensagemSucesso"] = "Cliente alterado com sucesso";

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Uma saída é remover todos os telefones e inserir os que estão na lista. Mas se você quiser ter o controle de quando um número foi alterado, você terá que armazenar o `id` de cada telefone, ai você faz o tratamento, se houver `id` faz `update`, senão, faz `insert`. Deu para entender?

Comment: Eu pensei nessa saída de remover tudo e adicionar tudo de novo, mas não consegui fazer o `Remove()`, tentei tanto quanto `Remove` quanto `RemoveRange`, mas acho que não desenvolvi tal função corretamente

Comment: Faça uma consulta, remova os Ids que não existem mais e atualize o resto